# is it possible that System.out.println is the cause for a java application to hang?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging

I developed a process using spring boot, which take about 7 hours to complete.
The initial version has a lot of "System.out.println" calls, for debug purpose.
When I run this process on eclipse, it runs until the end, with no problems.
But, If I run it directly on terminal, locally or on a cloud VM, after two or three hours, the application just stop. The process remains alive, but my debug messages stops, and the processing also stops.

Is it possible that this messages are somehow crashing, or blocking my process after some time?

If true, I can only imagine that eclipse has some mechanism to discard old console messages, once it has a config with console buffer max size, and this prevents application to stop.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Following JimN suggestion, about extracting info from threads, here is what I found:

```
2017-08-10 20:18:07
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode):

"JMX server connection timeout 210" #210 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8940994000 nid=0x5f07 in Object.wait() [0x000070000af63000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:168)
    - locked <0x000000076b9ea400> (a [I)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Connection(16)-192.168.0.103" #209 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f89416b9000 nid=0x6107 runnable [0x000070000ac59000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    - locked <0x000000076d161e10> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:550)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$28/1628264240.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x000000076bfcb750> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"RMI TCP Connection(15)-192.168.0.103" #202 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893fa2f000 nid=0x5d03 runnable [0x000070000ae5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    - locked <0x000000076b9e0b60> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:550)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$28/1628264240.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000007917cc068> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"RMI Scheduler(0)" #199 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f894200a800 nid=0x5703 waiting on condition [0x000070000ab57000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007917dab10> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Accept-0" #197 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8940c4e800 nid=0x5303 runnable [0x000070000a951000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:52)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:400)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:372)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" #196 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8940b82800 nid=0x4dcb waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"DestroyJavaVM" #195 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893e007800 nid=0x1c03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"taskExecutor-2" #18 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8940a36800 nid=0x5103 waiting on condition [0x000070000a84e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c0c30a28> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"taskExecutor-1" #16 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8940a35800 nid=0x4f03 waiting on condition [0x000070000a74b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c0c30a28> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Abandoned connection cleanup thread" #13 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893cd67000 nid=0x1007 in Object.wait() [0x000070000a545000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x00000006c0670568> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner[705927765:1502393500924]" #12 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893db0d800 nid=0x140f in Object.wait() [0x000070000a442000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x00000006c05939e0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893d000000 nid=0x4903 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread2" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893e042000 nid=0x4703 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893e041800 nid=0x4503 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893e040000 nid=0x4303 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893e03d000 nid=0x4103 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893d009800 nid=0x3103 in Object.wait() [0x0000700009d2d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x00000006c0025a38> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893d002000 nid=0x2f03 in Object.wait() [0x0000700009c2a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x00000006c002d248> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893e02c800 nid=0x2d03 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893e013000 nid=0x2503 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893e014000 nid=0x2703 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893e014800 nid=0x2903 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893e015000 nid=0x2b03 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f893c800000 nid=0x4b03 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 388
```

However, I am not sure what does it mean.

Comment: I would say the opposite, I often have long running Eclipse programs that hang due to the console being full

Comment: Outputting text to the console is time consuming compared to cpu processing and memory operations. But this wouldn't be the first place I would check if the system hangs. What else does the application do?

Comment: I wouldn't expect the application to hang once the content outgrows the console buffer. You would likely just not be able to scroll back further than the buffer which begs the question -> is anybody watching the console when this runs?

Comment: I have also seen a situation where someone selected some text in a console and further writing to it was inhibited - I do not remember what type of console though

Comment: I have seen what @ScaryWombat describes in Windows console.  If you have an active selection, it causes the console output to hang, and may eventually block the process if it writes a lot more to stdout.  Once I realize my mistake, I normally hit "Enter" to fix the problem.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Actually no, I am improving this to write this messages to a log file. I didn't test it after this change.

Comment: @Juan the aaplication is a kind of "web crawler" that runs over a spercific site. It get information from the site, like a list of products. Then, for each product, it opens the product page, and get the rest of information.
I created a thread executor and I enqueue a thread for each product. Currently, I am using a fixed thread pool, with a size of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes is it possible.  That is, if you write to `System.out`, and the output of the process is not being consumed, then eventually the buffer associated with the process' output stream will become full and the thread calling `System.out.println()` will be blocked.  However if you're running the program on the console then this wouldn't happen since the output of the process is being consumed by the console.

If you have a Java application hanging in a thread, you should get a thread dump to investigate the cause of the hang.  The following tools can generate a thread dump:  `jstack`, `jvisualvm`.  You could also use `jvisualvm`, `jconsole` or `jmc` to interactively inspect thread state.  All of these tools come with Oracle's JDK.

Comment: I connected to my process using jsoncole, found some interesting things.
I have a thread pool executor, with a size of 2.
Here is what I found for each of them:

Name: taskExecutor-1
State: WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@44d8e1f9
Total blocked: 12  Total waited: 5

Name: taskExecutor-2
State: WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@44d8e1f9
Total blocked: 18  Total waited: 7